# Using Remove-SPTrustedServiceTokenIssuer without Identity parameter

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2013

On my SharePoint server, I need to remove a trusted digital certificate from the list that I obtain using the PowerShell command `Get-SPTrustedSecurityTokenIssuer`. It is recommended to use the command `Remove-SPTrustedServiceTokenIssuer -Identity [Identity]`

However, the certificate I want to remove has no Identity set, i.e. when I obtain its details using `Get-SPTrustedSecurityTokenIssuer`, the Identity field returned is blank.

How can I remove this particular certificate using the `Remove-SPTrustedServiceTokenIssuer` without the Identity parameter? Or is there any other way to remove it from the trusted list?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by following the instructions at https://docops.ca.com/ca-single-sign-on-agent-for-sharepoint/12-52-sp1/en/configuring/configure-sharepoint/removing-claims-from-trusted-identity-providers